# calling phtml file is working in view page but not in cart page

Tags: shipping, phtml

using this [extension](https://github.com/5mehulhelp5/MagentoExtensions/tree/master/Magento%20Display%20Shipping%20estimation%20Block%20in%20Product%20view%20page)

i am displaying shipping prices per product in view page.

i am calling same phtml code in cart page : `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/mpassignproduct/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`

its not working.

**view.phtml :**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping.estimate.form'); ?>
```

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layout>
    <webdevlopers_productpageshipping_skeleton>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><file>css/productpageshipping.css</file></action>
        </reference>
        <block  name="shipping.estimate.form" type="webdevlopers_productpageshipping/estimate_form" template="webdevlopers/productpageshipping/estimate/form.phtml" />
    </webdevlopers_productpageshipping_skeleton>

    <webdevlopers_productpageshipping_left>
        <update handle="webdevlopers_productpageshipping_skeleton" />
        <reference name="left">
            <action method="insert"><block>shipping.estimate.form</block></action>
        </reference>
    </webdevlopers_productpageshipping_left>

    <webdevlopers_productpageshipping_right>
        <update handle="webdevlopers_productpageshipping_skeleton" />
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="insert"><block>shipping.estimate.form</block></action>
        </reference>
    </webdevlopers_productpageshipping_right>

    <webdevlopers_productpageshipping_estimate_estimate>
        <block type="webdevlopers_productpageshipping/estimate_result" name="shipping.estimate.result" template="webdevlopers/productpageshipping/estimate/result.phtml" output="toHtml" />
    </webdevlopers_productpageshipping_estimate_estimate>
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
          <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><file>css/productpageshipping.css</file></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info">
              <block name="shipping.estimate.form" type="webdevlopers_productpageshipping/estimate_form" template="webdevlopers/productpageshipping/estimate/form.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

**form.phtml**

```
<?php if ($this->isEnabled()): ?>
<div class="block block-shipping-estimate">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getTitle(); ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
    <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getDes(); ?></p>
    <ul class="shipping-estimation-form" id="shipping-estimation-form">
        <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('country')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="estimate_country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Country') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect(
                            ($this->getFieldValue('country') ? $this->getFieldValue('country') : $this->getConfig()->getDefaultCountry()),
                            'estimate[country_id]',
                            'estimate_country'
                        );
                    ?>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <input type="hidden" id="estimate_country" name="estimate[country_id]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getConfig()->getDefaultCountry())?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('region')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="estimate_region_id"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('region')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('region')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <select id="estimate_region_id" name="estimate[region_id]" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('State/Province') ?>" style="display:none;"<?php echo ($this->isFieldRequired('region') ? ' class="validate-select"' : '') ?>>
                        <option value=""><?php echo  Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Please select an option') ?></option>
                    </select>
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                   //<![CDATA[
                       $('estimate_region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getFieldValue('region_id')); ?>');
                   //]]>
                   </script>
                   <input type="text" id="estimate_region" name="estimate[region]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('region')) ?>"  title="<?php echo  Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text" style="display:none;" />
               </div>
            </li>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                new RegionUpdater('estimate_country', 'estimate_region', 'estimate_region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>);
            //]]>
            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($this->isFieldVisible('city')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="city"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('city')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('city')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo  Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('City') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input class="input-text<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('city')):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" id="estimate_city" type="text" name="estimate[city]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('city')) ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('postcode')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="estimate_postcode"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input class="input-text validate-postcode<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="estimate_postcode" name="estimate[postcode]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
       <?php endif; ?>
       <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('coupon_code')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="estimate_coupon_code"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('coupon_code')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('coupon_code')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Coupon Code') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input class="input-text <?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('coupon_code')):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="estimate_coupon_code" name="estimate[coupon_code]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('coupon_code')) ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
       <?php endif; ?>
       <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('cart')): ?>
            <li class="item radio">
                <label for="estimate_cart_yes"><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Include Cart Items') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="radio" id="estimate_cart_yes" name="estimate[cart]" value="1" <?php if ($this->useShoppingCart()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?> /><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Yes') ?>
                    <input type="radio" id="estimate_cart_no" name="estimate[cart]" value="0" <?php if (!$this->useShoppingCart()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?> /> <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('No') ?>
                </div>
            </li>
       <?php elseif ($this->useShoppingCart()):?>
            <input id="estimate_cart_yes" type="hidden" name="estimate[cart]" value="1" />
       <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('shipping-estimation-form');</script>
    <div class="actions">
        <span class="please-wait f-left" id="shipping-estimate-loading-message" style="display:none;">
            <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Loading rates...') ?>
        </span>
        <div class="f-right">
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getButton(); ?>" onclick="estimateProductShipping()" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Get a Quote') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="shipping-estimate-results" style="display:none">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function estimateProductShipping()
{
    var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>';
    var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input',
                    '.shipping-estimation-form select',
                    '#product_addtocart_form input',
                    '#product_addtocart_form select']);

    var validationResult = true;

    // Check the valid input
    if (!items.map(Validation.validate).all()) {
        return;
    }

    var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true);
    $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').show();
    $('shipping-estimate-results').hide();
    new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, {
        parameters: parameters,
        onComplete: function() {
            $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide();
            $('shipping-estimate-results').show();
        }
    });

}
//]]>
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: In cart page there can be multiple products. But in product view page there is one product. So in cart page how the shipping estimation will work for multiple products. To make it working for multiple products u need modify the block logic.

Comment: I am planning to display shipping charges inside cart table for each product.

Comment: Your block clss not able to deticet the product. You can specify one function and pass the product object and implement shipping logic in that function

Comment: this is our default.phtml= > pastebin.com/PavD3aJi can you post an answer with updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This block can call  that block  by direct call of phtml using below code:**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('webdevlopers_productpageshipping/estimate_form')->setTemplate('webdevlopers/productpageshipping/estimate/form.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: i placed code in default.phtml file. but it didt worked for me : http://pasted.co/3b8c9f38 can you please check did i placed code in right place.

Comment: checkout page : http://prnt.sc/aysnbq